# "Find my Device" not available in Update and Security Settings

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

I just upgraded to the big November Update of Windows 10 which brought in new features. But I didn't have one feature - "Find my device" in the update and security settings. Is it region specific? Or you have to enable something else in order to enable this feature?

[image: update and security settings]

Answer (score 0):

I think the complete update is not done, that is why you are not getting that option, Go again and update your windows - the update you need is  - > **Windows 10 Fall Update 1511**

Helpful Links :

https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/62342/windows-10-tip-enable-find-my-device

Comment: It does show version 1511.

Comment: OS Build 10586.11

Comment: Well there is no other option I think, rather than to update the windows latest build. "Find my device" come in windows 10 fall update 1511and higher only. You can check out your pc build by going to my computer -> Properties, you will can see the build and version number.

Comment: That's what i commented before.